# Iterate through all distinct dictionary values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, value-iteration

Assuming a list of dictionaries, the goal is to iterate through all the distinct values in all the dictionaries.

Example:

```
d1={'a':1, 'c':3, 'e':5}
d2={'b':2, 'e':5, 'f':6}
l=[d1,d2]
```

The iteration should be over `1,2,3,5,6`, does not matter if it is a set or a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set` with a comprehension:

```
d1 = {'a':1, 'c':3, 'e':5}
d2 = {'b':2, 'e':5, 'f':6}
L = [d1, d2]

final = set(j for k in L for j in k.values())
# {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set.union` to iterate over *distinct* values:

```
res = set().union(*(i.values() for i in (d1, d2)))

# {1, 2, 3, 5, 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `set`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain
d1={'a':1, 'c':3, 'e':5}
d2={'b':2, 'e':5, 'f':6}
l=set(chain.from_iterable([d1.values(),d2.values()]))
print( l )
```

**Output:**

```
set([1, 2, 3, 5, 6])
```

- `chain.from_iterable` to flatten the list

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `itertools.chain` and a generator expression:

```
from itertools import chain

set(chain.from_iterable(d.values() for d in l))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print list(set().union(a, b))
```

Pretty straight forward

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(set.union, map(set, map(dict.values, l))))
```

This outputs:

```
{1, 2, 3, 5, 6}
```